# Unexpected behavior for KernelMixtureDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have some data:

```
upL={0., -0.003, 0.003, -0.001, 0.005, 0.011, 0.007, 0.002, 0.006, 0.005, 
0.01, 0.014, 0.006, 0.009, 0.011, 0.01, 0.004, 0.01, 0.003, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.013, 0.019, 0.006, 0.009, 0.01, 0.005, 0.002, 0.006, 0.007, 
0.006, 0.005, 0.008, 0.007, 0.009, 0.004, 0.006, 0.01, 0.005, 0.006, 
0.005, 0.004, 0.003, 0.005, 0.01, 0.002, 0.01, 0.003, 0.007}
```

I am fitting a KernelMixtureDistrbution to it:

```
upKMD = KernelMixtureDistribution[upL]
```

It plots as expected. It provides some probability information as expected:

```
Probability[x >= .006, x \[Distributed] upKMD]

(* 0.541353 *)

Probability[x <= .008, x \[Distributed] upKMD]
(* 0.63786 *)
```

But when I attempt to combine these to get the probability of a range of x, it doesn't evaluate.

```
Probability[x >= .006 && x <= .008, x \[Distributed] upKMD]
```

When using `EstimatedDistribution` for example, this works as I would have expected.

```
upEND = EstimatedDistribution[upL,NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]];
Probability[x >= .006 && x <= .008, x \[Distributed] upEND]
(* 0.199284 *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon. The last four solutions were all known to me. Mysterious that your first solution (even more compact and readable than the example) works. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
upL = {0., -0.003, 0.003, -0.001, 0.005, 0.011, 0.007, 0.002, 0.006, 0.005, 
   0.01, 0.014, 0.006, 0.009, 0.011, 0.01, 0.004, 0.01, 0.003, 0.01, 0.01, 
   0.013, 0.019, 0.006, 0.009, 0.01, 0.005, 0.002, 0.006, 0.007, 0.006, 0.005,
    0.008, 0.007, 0.009, 0.004, 0.006, 0.01, 0.005, 0.006, 0.005, 0.004, 
   0.003, 0.005, 0.01, 0.002, 0.01, 0.003, 0.007};

upKMD = KernelMixtureDistribution[upL];
```

I think this is a bug; however, use any of the following forms as a workaround

```
Probability[.006 <= x <= .008, x \[Distributed] upKMD]

(*  0.179213  *)
```

or

```
CDF[upKMD, .008] - CDF[upKMD, .006]

(*  0.179213  *)
```

or

```
Subtract @@ CDF[upKMD, {.008, .006}]

(*  0.179213  *)
```

or

```
Probability[x <= .008, x \[Distributed] upKMD] - 
 Probability[x <= .006, x \[Distributed] upKMD]

(*  0.179213  *)
```

or

```
Subtract @@ Probability[{x <= .008, x <= .006}, x \[Distributed] upKMD]

(*  0.179213  *)
```